# Streaming with Peerjs and turnserver

Tags: javascript, web, webrtc, peerjs, rfc5766turnserver

I am trying to create a web application that allows a users desktop to be shared to others via desktop capture and peerjs.  So far I am able to share the screen when both devices are connected to the same NAT.  But when I try two symmetric NATs the connection does not go through.  So I did some research and I figured out I need a TURN Server.  For this I am using www.turnservers.com.  I am having some trouble with the syntax for sending the servers to the new peer object.  I keep getting the error Peer is not defined.  Here is what I have so far...

```
window.turnserversDotComAPI.iceServers(function(data) {
    var peer = new Peer(makeid(),{
        key: '**************', 
        config: {'iceServers': data} }
        );
});
```

Both API's...

http://www.turnservers.com/docs

http://peerjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try installing the peerjs module `npm install peerjs` and then require it in your javascript file `var peerjs = require('peerjs');`

I think that should fix your problem.